# how to convert the this jsp code to thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

can any body help me I want to change this code to thymeleaf ?

```
<a href="${contextRoot}/show/category/${category.id}"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need `${contextRoot}` anymore.

```html
<a th:href="@{/show/category/{id}(id=${category.id})}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a good practise to use a variable that stores the root-location. Think of a service that runs e.g. on localhost port 8080 BUT is accessible from the web over nginx behind the URL me.com/myService/ (port 80). In this use case @ or contextRoot produces dead-links for end users since Thymeleaf doesn't know anything about that. My solution is to store e.g. "me.com/myService/" in the application properties and add this attribute by default to the model and build links like:

```
<a th:href="|${myRoot}/show/category/${category.id}|"></a>
```

If you don't need to handle things like that go with Metroids' answer, it's a good answer.